# How can I programmatically find Bluebird's version number?

Tags: promise, bluebird

I have a breakpoint right after `bluebird = require('bluebird')`, but I haven't been able to find any obvious property of the form `bluebird.version`.

In jQuery you do `jQuery.fn.jquery`, so maybe Bluebird does something weird like that?

Bluebird version 3.3.3

I found this snippet in their Github [`Promise.version = "__VERSION__";`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/7cfa9f763a14e7b3e9fef30db5a32aecbbe337f5/src/promise.js#L783), but I haven't been able to access that.

Comment: Down vote? Being server side or client side has no bearing on this, either way I would need to validate this programatically.

Comment: I don't think you know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
console.log(require('bluebird/package.json').version);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I must do it at runtime. Got to validate the Bluebird instance that gets loaded.

Comment: You can do this during runtime?

Comment: If not, you are not including a bunch of critical information in your question.

Comment: I can not use the the info from the package.json file because this is a build pipeline that builds other web applications that might specify different versions of the library in their own package.json files.

In other words, from my app perspective, the Bluebird instances are dynamically loaded.

Comment: Or put differently, `require('bluebird/package.json').version` is build time, not runtime.

Comment: Alright, that's kind of important to include. I would suggest an alternative then. Given that you _probably_ don't support every version of bluebird because you're missing some feature in older version, just test for the existence of that feature. It's more reliable anyway.

Comment: That is a good suggestion! Not sure if its feasible in my situation, since I don't care for any specific feature other than compliance to vetted versions of the library.

Comment: If you're really worried about that, why not: A) ship your own version in a way that doesn't conflict. or B) don't use bluebird. A lot of bluebird is implementable with a couple of lines of code without polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Yeah, ideally we would completely drop it, I want that. But that means updating many lines of code across over 100 apps. So, no one is doing it any time soon :p

Comment: this gave me an idea, so simple, you can update que answer with something like: `const version = require('bluebird/package.json').version; const bluebird = require('bluebird'); bluebird.version = version;`

Comment: Still build time, but I can automate this with a regex.